# Wordpress $args now not searching our products/skus/etc (Big Commerce)

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming, searchbar

Our site's search.php is acting up awfully. I cannot get Ajax Search Lite to override the results; however, it has now quit even pulling item SKUs. So if I search '603402', it returns no results. It use to would show the product with that SKU. I'm really not sure what could be wrong, as nothing is different. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.`enter code here`

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#search-result
 *
 * @package
 * @subpackage 2022 Theme
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

get_header();
?>

<main id="main-content" class="main-content light product-archive-main search-template-main">

    <!-- // ------- Search Results - borrowed from Product Archive -->
    <section class="product-archive-section">
        <div class="layer-over container grid-container product-archive-content-container">
            <nav class="grid-item desktop-3 product-archive-menu desktop-menu" aria-label="All Products">
                <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'products-menu',
                    'menu' => 'Sonic Tools Store Menu'
                    )
                ); ?>
                <p class="caption product-archive-rep-callout">
                    <button class="simple-text-link footer-sales-link sales-form-trigger">Speak with a Sonic Rep</button> to discuss business solutions or to get a quote
                </p>
            </nav>
            <div class="grid-item desktop-9 product-archive-content">
                <?php
                    $search_string = get_search_query();
                    $args = array(
                        's'              => $search_string,
                        'posts_per_page' => 24,
                        'order'          => 'DESC',
                    );
                    $search_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
                ?>
                <?php if ( $search_posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <div class="product-archive-heading search-heading results">
                        <h1 class="section-heading no-margin-bottom bc-product-archive__title product-archive-headline">
                            <?php printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', 'my-theme' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-archive-filters">
                        <nav class="product-archive-filter-chip-wrapper" aria-label="Subcategories">
                            <small class="product-archive-small-label product-archive-filter-chips-label">Jump to:</small>
                            <ul class="product-archive-filter-chips">
                                <li class="product-archive-filter-chip product-all-menu-item">
                                    <button class="filter-chip simple product-all-menu-prompt" aria-controls="productsPocket" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <span class="chip-text">All Products</span>
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-archive-filter-chip">
                                    <a class="filter-chip simple product-archive-filter-chip-link" href="/products/categories/toolsets">
                                        <span class="chip-text">Complete Toolsets</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-archive-filter-chip">
                                    <a class="filter-chip simple product-archive-filter-chip-link" href="/products/categories/toolboxes">
                                        <span class="chip-text">Toolboxes</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-archive-filter-chip">
                                    <a class="filter-chip simple product-archive-filter-chip-link" href="/products/categories/toolboxes">
                                        <span class="chip-text">Modular Cabinets</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-archive-filter-chip">
                                    <a class="filter-chip simple product-archive-filter-chip-link" href="/products/categories/categories/sonic-foam-system">
                                        <span class="chip-text">Sonic Foam System</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="product-archive-filter-chip">
                                    <a class="filter-chip simple product-archive-filter-chip-link" href="/products/categories/categories/hand-tools">
                                        <span class="chip-text">Hand Tools</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="product-content-grid grid-col-4 search-items">
                        <?php
                            while ( $search_posts->have_posts() ) : $search_posts->the_post();
                                $postID = get_the_ID();
                                $featuredImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($postID));
                                $hero = $featuredImg ? $featuredImg[0] : get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/images/post-thumbnail-fallback.jpg'; ?>
                                <li class="search-item">
                                    <div class="content-card article-card search-content-card">
                                        <picture class="article-card-hero search-content-card-hero" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <img class="article-card-hero-image search-content-card-hero-image" src="<?php echo $hero; ?>" loading="lazy" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="400" height="200" />
                                        </picture>
                                        <div class="article-card-content search-content-card-inner">
                                            <h3 class="article-card-heading search-content-card-heading"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                            <p class="article-card-description"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="article-card-cta">
                                                <span class="secondary-button dark-text article-card-cta-button search-card-cta-button">
                                                    <span class="button-text">View</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="product-content-pagination">
                        <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <div class="product-archive-heading search-heading no-results">
                        <h1 class="section-heading no-margin-bottom bc-product-archive__title product-archive-headline">
                            <?php printf( esc_html__( 'No Results for: %s', 'my-theme' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?>
                        </h1>
                        <p class="intro-copy empty-search-state-message">No products or content matches you search. For products, try using the menu here to find a relevant category.</p>
                        <a class="button primary-button" href="/products">
                            <span class="button-text">View all Products</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>

<!-- // ------- Mobile Pocket -->
<div class="modal-overlay product-pocket-close product-archive-pocket-overlay" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<div id="productsPocket" class="product-archive-pocket" aria-live="assertive" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="product-archive-pocket-inner">
        <div class="product-archive-pocket-nav-heading">
            <h2 class="product-archive-pocket-nav-title">Tools & Storage Solutions</h2>
            <button id="productsPocketClose" class="close-button product-pocket-close product-archive-pocket-close">
                <div class="close-button-inner">
                    <span class="close-bar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="close-bar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">Close Products Menu</span>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <nav class="product-archive-pocket-nav-body product-archive-menu mobile-menu" aria-label="All Products">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'products-menu',
                'menu' => 'Sonic Tools Store Menu'
                )
            ); ?>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>


<?php
get_footer();
```